# Converting multipart file to an image object in golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to upload an image, resize it and then upload it to Amazon S3 in go, however I'm struggling to figure out how to convert the image from multipart.File to image.Image

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/mitchellh/goamz/aws"
    "github.com/mitchellh/goamz/s3"
    "github.com/nfnt/resize"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type ResizeController struct {
}

func NewResizeController() *ResizeController {
    return &ResizeController{}
}

func (rc ResizeController) Resize(c *gin.Context) {

    auth, err := aws.EnvAuth()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client := s3.New(auth, aws.EUWest)
    bucket := client.Bucket(os.Getenv("AWS_BUCKET_NAME"))

    file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("file")
    filename := header.Filename

    height := c.Query("height")
    width := c.Query("width")

    h64, err := strconv.ParseUint(height, 10, 32)
    w64, err := strconv.ParseUint(width, 10, 32)
    h := uint(h64)
    w := uint(w64)

    m := resize.Resize(w, h, file, resize.Lanczos3)

    err = bucket.Put("/content/"+filename, m, "content-type", s3.Private)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"filename": header.Filename})
}
```

I'm getting the error `controllers/resize_controller.go:43: cannot use file (type multipart.File) as type image.Image in argument to resize.Resize:`

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out, I just needed to use

`image, err := jpeg.Decode(file)`

Comment: Note that this will only decode JPG images. It would be better to use [`image.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode) which auto-detects the image format. But remember that you need imports for this to work, e.g. `import _ "image/png"`. See package doc of [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) for details.